# How can I view data from an apps Activity without having the code? (SCREEN SCRAPING + UIAutomation)

Tags: android, android-studio, screen-scraping, android-uiautomator, xposed

Hi everyone I have a problem and I don't know how to solve it.

For reference I have root privileges on my device.

It's a question related to domain of pentesting I suppose. But basically there's an app and I know how it's layout is structured from using UIAutomator. I want to **scrape** the live data that it presents in a list, mainly the TextView elements. After scraping these I want to programatically determine which element to click (hence trying UIAutomator to for clicking).

Unfortunately UIAutomator was too slow and not good for me. I have root so I figure something similar should be possible but I have no clue on where to start.

Basically I want to **scrape** data and perform UI scrolling, clicking and swiping programatically like Robot class in java.

1. Read TextViews contained inside a ViewGroup for the apps Activity
2. Click on one if a certain condition is met
3. Perform automatic scrolling if necessary
4. Perform clicks and swipes

I've read that Xposed can be used to read info by hooking provided you have access to the apps code but I do not. I have also tried to decompile the APK to find the methods at that Activity but didn't get anywhere.

Any advice?

Edit: I have already tried examining the API using Burp Suite. While this is also a solution and it works, I would rather have the alternative.

Comment: Have you looked into [`AccessibilityService`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/service)?

Comment: @MikeM.So if I understand correctly the macro apps on the playstore use this service and so can I. But I also need to be able to read the data not only perform UI Gestures on it. Is there any way I can combine this service with the ability to read element data like UIAutomator? I have root.

Comment: You just want to read data from `View`s, yeah? `AccessibilityService` can handle that. I wouldn't think you'd need any other tools, though I'd imagine it's going to be a little tedious to implement, but I kinda figured those other methods were, too.

Comment: @MikeM Wait so I can read window data given if I know the res ID using that? That's amazing. Going to give that a shot, thank you very much Mike!